# wpf how to change controls within a grid

Tags: wpf, controls

I started looking at wpf recently and am having a hard time wrapping my head around it.  I have written plenty of c++ and c# but xmal seems a bit foreign to me right now.  I have created a main window that has a grid.  Within the grid i have a user control that i dynamically create buttons.  Depending on which button the user presses the control should load another user control in place of the current control, kind of how a win7 phone would work... This is a desktop app not a phone app.. just wanted to give you an example of the desired result. I have looked at Pages and Navigation but i don't think this what i'm looking for. Can someone please point me in the right direction.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put a "ContentControl" in your Xaml
and than in your code change it's content, like:

ContentControl1.Content = new MyUserControl();

Comment: not sure i quite follow this, lets say i put a content control on my mainwindow, and at run time add a user control, my user control knows nothing of the containers its being put in.  If i click on a button in my user control how does it go about letting its parent know that is supposed to remove that control and replace it with another control... I think i'm making this harder then it really is.

Comment: @poco hmm, who told you the UserControl knows nothing of it's containers? this is WPF and everything works on a visual tree...
So, to change the ContentControl content it's as easy as making your userControl button do this: (this.Parent as ContentControl).Content = new UserControl2();